# Replace NaN values in Dataframe column by shifting columns over to the right

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I'm looking to split and shift data I have in my dataframe over into a column that contains NaNs

Upon reading in the data from a pdf and creating the table, the output is:

```
   Output
   |       Summary       |  Prior Years|1|2|3|4| 5 |6|7|8|9|10|  Total  |
   |---------------------|-------------|-|-|-|-|---|-|-|-|-|--|---------|
   |Total Value 3,700,000|     110     |-|-|-|5|NaN|-|-|-|-|--|3,815,000|  
   |Total Value 320,000  |     110     |-|-|-|5|NaN|-|-|-|-|--| 435,000 |
```

Due to the PDF format, reading in the data causes the first column to combine 'Total Value' and the expected value for 'Prior Years'

```
Expected Output
   |  Summary  |Prior Years| 1 |2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|  Total  |
   |-----------|-----------|---|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|--|---------|
   |Total Value| 3,700,000 |110|-|-|-|5|-|-|-|-|--|3,815,000|  
   |Total Value|  320,000  |110|-|-|-|5|-|-|-|-|--| 435,000 |
```

All the data after the '5' column that contains the NaNs is as expected

Is there a way to split the data in the 'Summary' column and have all the data shift over until the NaN columns are then occupied?

Comment: Is there a need to do that operand multiple time or just once for this column?

Comment: For right now, it's looking like the full datasets only require this to be done once

Comment: @DominickR, posted a solution, does it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way to do it. based on the stated assumption that values upto column 5 are to be shifted from left, and Summary column is to break into two columns

```
# shift the values from 'Prior Years' thur column 5 to right and assign to col '1' thru '5'
df.loc[:,"1":"5"]=df.loc[:,"Prior Years":"5"].shift(axis=1)

# split the summary into text (Total Value) and the value, and assign to
# Summary and Prior Years columns

df[['Summary','Prior Years']]=df['Summary'].str.strip().str.extract(r'(\D*).*?([\d\,\.]*)' )
df
```

```
    Summary       Prior Years     1     2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  Total
0   Total Value     3,700,000   110     -   -   -   5   -   -   -   -   --  3,815,000
1   Total Value       320,000   110     -   -   -   5   -   -   -   -   --  435,000
```

Comment: This was great help! Thank you for the post, this is excellent

Answer (score 1):

Just ffill through axis = 1

```
df.ffill(axis=1)
```

After that you can easily replace your 4 columns to np.nan

```
df['4'] = df['4'].replace(5,np.nan)
```

Comment: This is a good tip, however, this is only a portion of the data. Some of the data after does not have the value '5' in that column. I'm looking to be able to shift it all over, rather than replace

Comment: In this case then what should be the values of 4? If they are precious just isolate them on a series and reappend after ffill

Comment: In the "Summary" column, reading the PDF into a DataFrame mistakenly joins values. I essentially want to split the "total" str and the int that is contained in the column, and have everything slide one column to the right

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `df.shift()`:

```py
df.shift(periods_to_be_shifted, axis = 1)
```

In your case the `periods_to_be_shifted = 1`, try this:

```py
df.shift(1, axis = 1)
```

Comment: .shift just moves everything over one. I need to keep the data after the NaNs in the same place. Essentially, I want to split the data that's merged in the "summary" column, and have it all slide over once

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what dtype all of your columns are, but something like this should work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# example dataframe (leaves off last few columns, which aren't relevant)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Summary': ['Total Value 3,700,000', 'Total Value 320,000'], 'Prior Years': [110, 110],
                   '1': ['-', '-'], '2': ['-', '-'], '3': ['-', '-'], '4': [5, 5], '5': [np.nan, np.nan],
                   '6': ['-', '-']})

# create list of column names, drop na column, and rename relevant columns (cols 1 - 5, just shift each name back by one)
columns = df.columns.to_list()
new_col_dict = {columns[i]: columns[i + 1] for i in range(1,6)}
df.drop(columns=['5'], inplace=True)
df.rename(columns=new_col_dict, inplace=True)

# split up Summary column (based on spaces)
df.loc[:, 'Prior Years'] = df.Summary.str.split(" ").apply(lambda x: x[2])
df.loc[:, 'Summary'] = df.Summary.str.split(" ").apply(lambda x: x[0]) + " " + df.Summary.str.split(" ").apply(lambda x: x[1])

# if you want the "Prior Years" column to be int type:
df.loc[:, 'Prior Years'] = df['Prior Years'].str.replace(',', '')
df.loc[:, 'Prior Years'] = df['Prior Years'].astype(int)

# re-order dataframe columns, if you care to
df = df[['Summary', 'Prior Years', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']]
```